# addthis, google analytics and google plus share - not tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-plus, addthis

I'm trying to track which social media are being clicked. I'm using two version of add this. One is the vertical one that looks like http://postimage.org/image/4sngil7t5/. Another one is the one that looks like http://postimage.org/image/6lh6ffe89/

I've read over http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api-#events and have something that looks like

```
function track_add_this(evt){

_gaq.push(['b._trackEvent', 'Testing',evt.data.service+'-widget-click','/Moretest-2012_'+recipe_name+'/']);
console.info(evt.data.service);

 }

 addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.share', track_add_this);
```

When I use the 2nd addthis widget, it is tracking the "evt.data.service" in my GA. When I choose the google+ social media from there, it is working fine.

But when I use the 1st addthis widget and click on the google+ social, it's not tracking at all. In fact, the console is not printing anything therefore it's not tracking in my GA. But when I click on any other social media in the 1st addthis widget, it is tracking fine.

Is there a bug in the 1st addthis widget? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: unless I'm missing something, neither one of the tinypic.com links you gave show what you are talking about...

Comment: But anyways, perhaps your 2nd addthis widget is overwriting the first addthis object? Have you tried removing the 2nd widget to confirm?

Comment: I've re-edited my post to include working images. Thank you for letting me know. Anywho, sadly those widgets are all template-based and cannot remove them without affecting a lot of pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could also be an issue related to how the addthis widgets are included on your page.

If one of them is in a Iframe, your code might now have access to ga.js Also conole might be separating logs from different frames and hence you can't see the console logs.